# Is there a way to make a regular ruby class use a erb/haml template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Basically, I have a class that outputs some html:

```
class Foo
  include ActionView::Helpers

  def initialize(stuff)
    @stuff = stuff
  end

  def bar
    content_tag :p, @stuff
  end

end
```

so I can do:  Foo.new(123).bar

and get "<p>123</p>"

...  But what I really want to do is something like this:

```
class Foo << ActionView::Base

  def initialize(stuff)
    @stuff = stuff
  end

  def bar
    render :template => "#{Rails.root/views/foo/omg.html.erb}"
  end

end

# views/omg.html.erb

<h1>Wow, stuff is <%= @stuff %></h1>
```

and then do Foo.new(456).bar and get "<h1>Wow, stuff is 456</h1>"

Comment: Try look at http://yehudakatz.com/2009/07/19/rails-3-the-great-decoupling/ will probably help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call [erb](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/classes/ERB.html) directly?  Something like:

```
def bar
  template = ERB.new(File.read("#{Rails.root}/views/foo/omg.html.erb"))
  template.result(binding)
end
```

Comment: I don't suppose you know how to do this but render a haml template instead?